# codeigniter 3 URL Remap

Tags: codeigniter-routing, codeigniter-3

I am trying to remap all old URLs `http://www.example.com/ipranges.php?reqinfo=180.94.79.0-180.94.79.255` in my codeigniter 3 but its not working. here is my route for this. Can someone help? Thanks

```
$route['ipranges.php?reqinfo=/(:any)'] = "ipinfo/ipranges/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

-`codeigniter`  is using `uri` segments , and there is "`ipranges.ph`p..."

in your routes which is not allowed and can't be used in codeigniter.

-In codeigniter url->

there is 1st segment which indicates controller ,
second segment point to method and 
third and so on, are the parameters to method.

-so here is url=> `www.example.com/controller/method/parameter......`

-if you are using routing,than you can remap them as
-----`www.example.com/slug`

--Here in `routes.php`

```
$route['slug'] = "controller/method/$1";
```